# How to refer to outer scope item inside rust macro?

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming

I'm writing a `proc-macro` that receives a trait-item and returns some modules based on this trait.

input

```rust
#[my_macro]
pub trait MyTrait {
    // ...
    // ... fn items
    // ...
}
```

output

```rust
pub mod my_mod_a {
    //...
}

pub mod my_mod_b {
    //...
}
// etc...
```

The question is, I have an item (a struct or an enum) defined outer of macro item what i want to refer from the generated code.

Returning to the example:

Defining something like this, a trait-item to apply the macro, and the outer item that can be at any scope in the project for example `crate::error::Error`

```rust
// src/lib.rs

// enum for error handling defined by user what i want to refer from generated code
pub enum MyOuterEnum {
    GoodError,
    BadError,
}

#[my_macro]
pub trait MyTrait {
    
    // some function that return type would be transform into a result
    fn my_fn() -> u32;
}
```

`How can I pass this element to the macro and thus refer to it?`

As an example let's say I want to transform the output of the function `my_fn` from `T` to `Result<T>`, then I should get an output like this:

```rust
// possible output referencing the element outside the macro input item

pub mod my_generated_mod {
    pub trait MyTrait {
        // my function with return type changed
        fn my_fn() -> Result<u32, crate::MyOuterEnum>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `super` in a path to refer to the parent module. Its not clear to me exactly which items you want to use in the child module for your macro, but you'll either want:

- a path per item - like `super::MyOuterEnum` - or
- a wildcard import - `use super::*;` - to include *everything* from the parent into the child